# update a HTML input field with the data coming from a external Javascript Websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, real-time, real-time-updates

I am new to JavaScript, not sure if this very basic question. I've created a Bitcoin Price update dashboard using the data fetched from the external WebSocket. I managed to get the data from the WebSocket and display it on the console tab and display the data in a h1 tag. The price updates every seconds. Now i need to show the price in a html field. i tried but it's kinda hard for me.

I have provided the code snippets below as well as external Websocket from where I am pulling the data.

Please let me know how should I insert the row dynamically into a HTML input field. Thank you so much in advance

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="btcpricenow" readonly />
<script>
 var priceSocket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
  liveprice = document.getElementById("btcpricenow");
 priceSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
  var liveprice = JSON.parse(event.data);
  liveprice.innerText = parseFloat(liveprice.p).toFixed(2);
 };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `liveprice` to be the HTML element, and then reset it inside your function to be the parsed `event.data`. Don't reset the variable like that, just set a new variable instead. Also, when you are putting a value inside an `input` element use `value`, not `innerHTML`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="btcpricenow" readonly>
<script>
  let priceSocket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
    liveprice = document.getElementById("btcpricenow");
  priceSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    liveprice.value = parseFloat(data.p).toFixed(2);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you its working!!

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
const data= JSON.parse(event.data);
let liveprice = document.getElementById("btcpricenow");
liveprice.value = parseFloat(data.p).toFixed(2) || "";
```

Comment: it worked!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Kinglish I set an operator for this problem to set the default value to "" if null or 0 or false

Comment: Oh yes it was a typo